# Functions near any Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, optimization, supremum-and-infimum

Let $\operatorname{Lip}\subseteq C([0,1]^d,\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the set of all Lipschitz functions from $[0,1]^d$ to $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Which *non-affine* functions $f \in C(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^d)$ satisfy:

There exists some $\epsilon\geq \delta\triangleq K\epsilon>0$ such that, for every ${g} \in Lip$ and every $g_1,g_2 \in Ball_{\epsilon}({g})$
$$
\inf_{
         \underset{B,A\in Mat_{d\times d}(\mathbb{R})}{a,b \in \mathbb{R}^d}
}
\sup_{x \in [0,1]^d} \big\|(a + A\, f (B\, g_1(x)+b)) - g_2(x)\big\|_2 < \delta.
$$

Intuitively, I would expect that it's necessary for $f$ to be Lipschitz, maybe contractive.

**Note:**
$Ball_{\epsilon}(g)\triangleq \left\{h \in C([0,1]^d;\mathbb{R}^d):\, 
\sup_{x \in [0,1]^d} \big\|h(x)- g(x)\big\|_2<\epsilon
\right\}$ (for $\epsilon >0$ and $g \in C([0,1]^d;\mathbb{R}^d)$).

Comment: 1). you wrote $\subseteq$ and then $\in$. 2). you write $C([0,1]^d,\mathbb{R}^d)$ but then say 'from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to itself'. 3). "Which ... for which" doesn't make sense; I can't read it. 4). its --> it's

Comment: what's Ball$_\epsilon(g)$? also, "intuitive, would..." has no subject (in the grammatical sense).

Comment: It refers to the $\epsilon$-ball in metric defining the compact-open topology on $C([0,1]^d;\mathbb{R}^d)$; I added details to clarify.

Comment: What is the context of this problem? Does it have something to do with neural networks?

Comment: @timur no it has come up in control theory; where $g_1(x)$ is the current position of a particle at time $t=1$ and $g_2(x)$ is the target position of the particle at time $t=2$.

Comment: do you want to find all functions $f$ that satisfy this or just one?

Comment: One is a good starting point; but I would like a "reasonable" sufficient condition satisfied by more than one function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a complete characterization, but here's a pretty broad sufficient condition:

> There are some nonsingular $T$ and $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that for any $\eta > 0$, there is some $r > 0$ such that $\|f(x) - f(x_0) - T(x - x_0)\| < r\eta$ in the ball $B_r(x_0)$.

Intuitively, this just says that $f$ can be rescaled to be arbitrarily close to affine. Also, it's worth noting that $T$ and $x_0$ are only fixed for convenience -- they need not be fixed so long as $\|T^{-1}\|$ is bounded.

The condition can be satisfied, for example, in the following "global" or "local" senses:

- There is some nonsingular affine map $S$ with $\|f(x) - S(x)\|$ bounded on $\mathbb{R}^d$.
- There is a point $x_0$ at which $f$ is differentiable with nonsingular total derivative (Jacobian).

These imply e.g. that it is not necessary for $f$ to be Lipschitz.

To prove our condition is sufficient, suppose we are given some $g, \varepsilon$. Fix $R > \sup_x \|g(x)\| + \varepsilon$, let $\eta > 0$, and take $r > 0$ satisfying our condition for $\eta$. Then setting $b = x_0$, $B = rR^{-1}I$, so $Bg_1(x) + b \in B_r(x_0)$ for $x \in [0, 1]^d$, and also setting $A = B^{-1}T^{-1}$, and $a = -B^{-1}b - Af(x_0)$, we have
\begin{align*}
\|a + Af(Bg_1(x) + b) - g_1(x)\| 
&= \|A(f(Bg_1(x) + b) - f(x_0) - T(Bg_1(x) + b))\| \\
&\leq \|A\| \|f(Bg_1(x) + b) - f(x_0) - T(Bg_1(x) + b)\| \\
&\leq \|A\| r \eta \\
&= R\|T^{-1}\|\eta
\end{align*}
so by the triangle inequality, $\inf_{a, b, A, B} \sup_x \|a + Af(Bg_1(x) + b) - g_2(x)\| \leq R\|T^{-1}\|\eta + 2\varepsilon$ for every $\eta > 0$, hence it's bounded by $\delta = 2\varepsilon$.

Comment: Since the $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$, do you believe you can modify your argument so $\delta$ is of the form $\delta= k \epsilon$ with $0<k<1$ instead of $k=2$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's actually impossible to get below $k\varepsilon$ in general for $k < 2$, at least in the case where $f$ is affine. I'll think about this and try to come up with a proof.

Comment: Maybe if it additionally satisfies some sort of local contraction (in a Hoelder/Lipschitz sense) then this could work

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same thing, if locally, $\|f(x)-f(y)\|\leq k \|x-y\|^{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha\geq 1$?

Comment: It's not hard to show that you can't do better than $\varepsilon$ in general for any $f$. Let $0 < \alpha < \varepsilon$, and let $v \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with $\|v\| = \alpha$. Then take $g = 0$, and $g_1, g_2$ such that there are points $x_1, x_2$ with $g_1(x_1) = g_1(x_2)$ and $g_2(x_1) = v$, $g_2(x_2) = -v$. But then $a + Af(Bg_1(x) + b)$ has distance at least $\alpha$ from $g_2(x)$ at at least one of $x = x_1$, $x = x_2$.

Comment: Do you believe the same would be true if the question was posed instead in $L^1_{\mu}(\mathbb{R}^d;\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $\mu$ is a finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you would modify the question to accommodate the new setting in $L^1_\mu(\mathbb{R}^d; \mathbb{R}^d)$ (for example: does $g$ lie in this space? do we now use $\int \| h \| \,d\mu$ as the norm, instead of $\sup_x \|h(x)\|_2$?), so it might be good to ask this in a new question

Comment: Fair enough, if instead we stay in $C(\mathbb{R}^d;\mathbb{R}^d)$ and relax the optimization problem a bit to
$$
\inf_{
         \underset{B,A\in Mat_{d\times d}(\mathbb{R})}{a,b \in \mathbb{R}^d,n \in \mathbb{N};n\geq 1}
}
\sup_{x \in [0,1]^d} \big\|(a + A\, f^n (B\, g_1(x)+b)) - g_2(x)\big\|_2 < \delta,
$$
then do you believe this would help?  This we could access "almost polynomials" of degree $d$ instead of only almost affine functions?

Comment: Assuming by $f^n(x)$ you mean $(f(x))^n$, I think this would allow $f$ to be "almost" a root of an affine function, i.e. $f(x) \approx (Tx)^{1/n}$. That said, it's not clear to me what your goal is -- do you want to find a condition satisfied by a function $f$ which would allow you to distort any $g_1$ (via some affine transformed function based on $f$) to be within $\delta = k\varepsilon$ of $g_2$ (for $k < 1$)?

Comment: because, for example, in your new problem we still cannot get below $\varepsilon$ in general, by the same argument as the one I made above.